# Interacting with Oauth1 API in cloudflare worker (Flickr)

Tags: javascript, oauth, flickr, cloudflare-workers, webcrypto

I'm needing to interact with the Flickr api from a cloudflare worker, but it's turning out to be exceedingly tricky.

My initial idea was to reach for the `oauth1.0a` library, but unfortunately it requires being passed a synchronous signature function. This is an issue because I need to use WebCrypto on the worker and it only exposes an asynchronous API.

Are there any other libraries I can use? I've currently spent hours trying to manually craft the request but keep getting errors saying the signature is bad.

This is my current attempt using someone's fork of `oauth1.0a` that adds support for an async signature function. This currently results in an "invalid_signature" response:

```js
import OAuth from 'oauth-1.0a';

const CALLBACK_URL = "https://localhost:3000/oauth/callback";

const encoder = new TextEncoder();

async function signData(baseString: string, keyString: string) {
  return await crypto.subtle.importKey(
    'raw',
    encoder.encode(keyString),
    { name: 'HMAC', hash: 'SHA-1' },
    false,
    ['sign']
  ).then(key => {
    return crypto.subtle.sign(
      "HMAC",
      key,
      encoder.encode(baseString)
    );
  }).then(signature => {
    let b = new Uint8Array(signature);
    // base64 digest
    return btoa(String.fromCharCode(...b));
  });
}

export async function getRequestToken(consumerKey: string, consumerSecret: string) {
  const url = "https://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token";
  const token = {
    key: consumerKey,
    secret: consumerSecret
  }
  const oauth = new OAuth({
    consumer: token,
    signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
    // @ts-ignore
    hash_function: signData,
  });
  const requestData = {
    url,
    method: 'GET',
    data: {
      oauth_callback: CALLBACK_URL
    }
  };

  // @ts-ignore
  const authorisedRequest = await oauth.authorizeAsync(requestData, token);
  let params = new URLSearchParams();
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(authorisedRequest)) {
    params.append(key, value as string);
  }
  const response = await fetch(requestData.url + `?${params}`, {
    method: requestData.method,
  });

  const body = await response.text();
  const parsedBody = oauth.deParam(body);
  return parsedBody;
}
```